# Issue with drawing text on canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

i am drawing text on canvas using drawText() method.But when line is bigger then screen it is cutting text means if line is greater than screen size then it should come to new line,but it is not happening.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is `StaticLayout`.

You can use `Android.text.StaticLayout` class and call it's `draw(Canvas)` to draw text which wraps onto the next line.

Comment: Thanks, but its drawing canvas not text on canvas ?

Comment: Cheers. Sorry I couldn't get back to you earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The `Canvas.drawText` methods do not automatically handle line-wrapping. You will have to do this yourself. You could try using the breakText methods in the [Paint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html) object—not sure if these break on word boundaries, or simply on whole characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
mTextLayout = new DynamicLayout([charseq], paint, width,
                Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);
```

This will layout your text limited to a specific width.